# Erro ao importar múltiplos arquivos XML - Codeigniter PHP

Tags: php, codeigniter, xml

Estou tentando importar arquivos `xml` para o banco de dados.
Neste exemplo, eu teria 2 arqurivos `xml` para importar.
**Obs: O XML é uma CTS de transporte rodoviário.**
Eu tentei fazer da seguinte forma:

```
$i = 1;
$TotalArquivos = count($_FILES['arquivo']);

if($TotalArquivos==$i)
{
    echo $TotalArquivos." <<< TOTAL >>> "; 
} else 
{
    foreach($_FILES['arquivo'] as $file)
    {
        if($_FILES['arquivo']['tmp_name'][$i]==false) exit; //---> linha 39 do arquivo importarCET.php
        $xml[$i] = simplexml_load_file($_FILES['arquivo']['tmp_name'][$i]); 
        print_r(json_encode($xml[$i]))."<Br>";    
        $i++;
    }               

}
```

Dessa forma, a minha ideia era dentro do $i, contar quantos tem e parar no total.
Mas ele continua buscando... e gera o seguinte erro:

> A PHP Error was encountered Severity: Notice Message:  Undefined
> offset: 2 Filename: libraries/importarCTE.php Line Number: 39

Onde estou errando?

Comment: o `$i` deve começar do `0` porque é um `array` produzido pelo PHP então começa com `0`, se tem duas posições e 0 e 1 as posições do `array`

Comment: Tem também problema no código, você faz um `foreach` e não precisa posicionar nada já tem a valor na outra `variavel`

Comment: Certo. Eu tentei de N formas, usei $i=0 também. Tentei usar a $file mas não obtive êxito. :-(

Comment: Tentei $file[$i] também

Comment: Viu o código?..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Um exemplo mínimo de como obter as informações de um campo `<input type="file"/>` com PHP:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div>
  <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="arquivo[]" multiple="multiple"/>
    <button>Enviar</button>
  </form>
  </div>
  <div>
  <?php
    if (empty($_FILES['arquivo']) === false){
      for($i = 0; $i < count($_FILES['arquivo']['name']); $i++){
        //$_FILES['arquivo']['name']
        //$_FILES['arquivo']['type']
        //$_FILES['arquivo']['tmp_name']
        //$_FILES['arquivo']['error']
        //$_FILES['arquivo']['size']
        simplexml_load_file($_FILES['arquivo']['tmp_name'][$i]);         
        //...
      }
    }
  ?>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Bom dia, neste caso, eu estou usando Codeigniter. Mas parece bem interessante. Irei testar e retorno. Obg pela ajuda.

Comment: Bom dia, obrigado, deu certinho.